# positioning elements relatively to an image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position images relatively to the main image - the rest of the images should be positioned on the left, right and top of the main image.

```
   <div class="top">
            <img class="top__position" src="https://place-hold.it/300x150" alt="">
            <div class="top__winner"><img src="https://place-hold.it/80x80" alt=""></div>  
            <div class="top__winner"><img src="https://place-hold.it/80x80" alt=""></div>  
            <div class="top__winner"><img src="https://place-hold.it/80x80" alt=""></div>  
   </div>
```

I struggle with the execution of this task - I put the position relative on the top__position class and position absolute on the top__winner and top:

```
.top__winner:nth-of-type(1) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;

}
```

Comment: Note that the `:nth-of-type` pseudo-class refers to _Element Type_. It explicitly doesn't mean `:nth-of-class`. Your selector could be rewritten as something like: `.top div:nth-of-type(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

> I put the position relative on the top__position

You need to put `position: relative` on `.top`, not `.top__position`.

EDIT:

`position: absolute` absolutely positions (i.e. obeys `top`,`left`,`bottom`,`right` properties) an element **relative** to it's nearest positioned (`relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`) ancestor.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this I presume

[Click here for Javascript Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a51bhLd6/1/)

```
.top {
position: relative;
padding: 0 0; // Your image is 80px high so this will give 20px under
height: 100%;
min-height: 350px;
}

.top .top__position {
max-width: calc(100% - 200px);
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.top div.top__winner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.top div.top__winner:nth-child(2) {
  right: 0;
  left: unset;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.top div.top__winner:nth-child(3) {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

looks like a typical grid layout.

If i understood the position :
one small image on top of the big, then the 2 others on both sides.

it requires a 3 col grid to start from , *i used margin for alignment, you can reset them or use dedicated rules you will find reading a tutorial* , possible example below:

```css
.top {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  width: max-content;/* shrinks it to the width used by the content */
  margin: auto;/* if you want it at center */
  background:tomato; /* demo, to see where it stands */
}

.top>img {/* Note :this one is nth-child(1) , first child of .top*/
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  margin: 0;
}

.top__winner:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 2;
  margin: auto;
}

.top__winner:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  margin: auto 2px;
}

.top__winner:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
  margin: auto 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <img class="top__position" src="https://place-hold.it/300x150" alt="">
  <div class="top__winner"><img src="https://place-hold.it/80x80" alt=""></div>
  <div class="top__winner"><img src="https://place-hold.it/80x80" alt=""></div>
  <div class="top__winner"><img src="https://place-hold.it/80x80" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Some usefull ressources :

https://gridbyexample.com/ &

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

> **`grid-template-columns`** , **`grid-template-rows`**
>
> Defines the columns and rows of the grid with a space-separated list of values. The values represent the track size, and the space between them represents the grid line.

---

> **`grid-column`**, **`grid-row`**
>
> Shorthand for `grid-column-start` + `grid-column-end`, and `grid-row-start` + `grid-row-end`, respectively.